# Multivariate calculus: how to differentiate the trace of inverse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning, matrix-calculus

Let  $C$ be $m \times n$.

Let $\Sigma$ be $n \times n$ and symmetric. Note that $C \Sigma C^T$ will also be symmetric in this case .

Also let $A$ be $m \times m$.

I am faced the following:

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}( [C \Sigma C^T]^{-1}A)}{\partial C}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}( [C \Sigma C^T]^{-1}A)}{\partial \Sigma}$$

I read the matrix cookbook but I am still having trouble to solve these 2 quantities. Can someone kindly guide me through this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 M &= C\Sigma C^T \cr
 B &= M^{-1}AM^{-1} \cr
}$$
Write the function and its differential in terms of these new variables 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A:M^{-1} \cr\cr
df &= -A:(M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1}) \cr
   &= -B:dM \cr
   &= -B:(dC\,\Sigma C^T+C\Sigma\,dC^T+C\,d\Sigma\,C^T) \cr
   &= -(BC\Sigma+B^TC\Sigma):dC - (C^TBC):d\Sigma \cr
}$$
The colon denotes the inner/Frobenius product, which is a compact infix notation for the trace $$X:Y={\rm tr}(X^TY)$$

The respective gradients are seen to be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}
   &= -(B+B^T)\,C\Sigma \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\Sigma}
   &= -C^TBC \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Hi @greg, can you elaborate on how you get the first step $df = -A : (M^{-1}dM M^{-1})$ please ? Because my understanding is that $d tr(A^T M^{-1}) = tr(d(A^T M^{-1})) = tr(A^T d(M^{-1}MM^{-1}))$ and at this stage, product rule should be applied to $d(M^{-1}MM^{-1})$ , right ?

Comment: Since $\big(M^{-1}MM^{-1}=M^{-1}\big)$ we really want is $dM^{-1}$. What got substituted in the first step was precisely that $$dM^{-1}=-M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1}$$